# Can I run an asychronous flow after insert?

Tags: visual-workflow, asynchronous

To create a flow that runs asynchronously I have to add a condition with `ISCHANGED` or configure it to run *only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements*.

The `ISCHANGED` function does not trigger the flow when a record is inserted (even if you could consider that the data *changed* from null to something), so I tried to use a formula that says `ISNEW() || ISCHANGED( {!$Record.MyField__c} )`.

[image]

It doesn't work, the system refuses to activate the flow, I can't figure a way to make the flow run after asynchronously after insert.

I could synchronously create a platform event and put the logic in a platfom event triggered flow, but it looks too complicated for such a simple requirement, I guess there's a much more simple way, right ?

Comment: So, for clarification, you're trying to use ISNEW/ISCHANGED in the asynchronous part of the code?

Comment: @sfdcfox I added a picture to make things clear, it's in the trigger config that I tried to use these functions.

Comment: What did you set *When to Run the Flow for Updated Records* to? If you're using ISCHANGED, it should be set to *Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements*, because otherwise it can never fire.

Comment: Because I got the error "For a path that runs asynchronously, configure the flow to run only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements or select the Is Changed operator in a condition." But that changed nothing.